# HTML : create a table with n number of rows using angular 8

Tags: html, angular, angular8

I want to create a table with 20 rows.

I am getting some of the data from backend, say for 3 rows. for next 17 rows, cell for each row should be empty.

using the below code will only give me the row as per the data which is 3 in number

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let group of groups">
        <td><h1>{{group.name}}</h1></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to try sth like below, but syntax wise things are not working.

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor=" let group of groups">
        <td><h1>{{group.name}}</h1></td>
    </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let x of 20 - groups.length">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> 20 - groups.length should be an array, but it is a number

Answer (score 0):

If in the right way - after receiving of backend data just need to add javascript logic and transform array.
Or another more reusable way, you need to write a custom pipe which will return transformed array.

```
*ngFor="let group of (groups | myCustomPipe)"
```

Comment: Do you mean, i need to add 17 empty rows more in that pipe implementation for this array

Comment: yes, inside pipe - need to create a new empty array and fill newly created array with groups and if there still less then 20 length then fill the rest of array items with null till there will be 20 elements in array, then return this new array from pipe (transform method).

Comment: that's make sense, but is it possible to do the same with any other way, because in pipe first we are adding the null value in array and then we are rendering it. cannot we direct render it when we know it is going to be null.

Comment: with pipe it renders directly, just logic which you wrote `x of 20 - groups.length` - will be inside pipe with javascript syntax

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to handle this

In .ts file

1. create another array with empty string and keep the size to be 20.

In .html file

2. Iterate through the newArray.length an use the index in groups[i] to display the value. Otherwise it will display nothing and generate extra table cells for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `20 - groups.length` is a number minus a number so it's expected that you will have a number. Something you can do on the typescript side is push empty rows to your groups array.

```
this.groups = dataFromBackend;
const emptyObject = {
    id: null,
    name: null,
    ...
}

while (groups.length < 20) {
    groups.push(emptyObject);
}
```